# Script to pass Y as an answer when asked during execution of command line

Tags: vbscript

Can we write a VBScript to pass Y as an answer when asked during execution of command line. The scenario is as shown below.

**Example output from command line**

```
C:\Users>ctrk -h datafile

 Do you want to copy the test generated files to inbox(y/n):y
Trying to generate beat file  ...

Checking file creation.....
Heart file    : C:\Program Files (x86)\FWI\data\beat.zip  created

Press 'ENTER' to exit.
```

I tried the following solution

```
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WSHShell.Run "%comspec% /c "& " echo y  | ctr -h datafile , 1, true"
```

But it is giving the following issue-
**Example output from command line**

```
C:\Users\>echo y  | ctrk -h datafile

 Do you want to copy the test generated files to inbox(y/n):Trying to generate beat file  ...

Checking file creation....
Heart file    : C:\Program Files (x86)\FWI\data\beat.zip  created

Press 'ENTER' to exit.

Exception occurred. Refer to the error log for details.
```

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Comment: Look at `Write()` method of [`WScript.StdOut`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c61dx86d(v=vs.84).aspx) and the `ReadLine()` method of [`WScript.StdIn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y8934a7(v=vs.84).aspx) stream objects you should be able to figure it out from there.

Comment: Once you've had a go if you are having a specific problem post the code by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35914641/edit) and we will try to help.

Comment: I tried the solution given by @Lankymart but it did not work out

Comment: @Test123 How is what you have posted there anything like [my suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914641/script-to-pass-y-as-an-answer-when-asked-during-execution-of-command-line#comment59491948_35914641)? `WSHShell.Run` is not the same as using `Set WSHExecObj = WSHShell.Exec("...")` then accessing the `StdIn` and `StdOut` streams via the `WSHExecObj` object variable.

Comment: You want to use `WScript.StdOut.Writeline("Y")` to send the `Y` character to the Standard Output buffer, [here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36013861/692942).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WSHShell.Run "%comspec% /c "& "ctr -h datafile , 1, false"
wait(2)
WSHShell.Sendkeys "y"
wait(2)
WSHShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```