# From VBS to BAT and back: Taking user inputs from the command line to VBS

Tags: variables, batch-file, command-line, vbscript, cmd

is there a way to start a *.bat from a *.vbs, then get the users command line input into a *.bat variable and give it back to vbscript code?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards.

Tommy

Comment: Why don't you simply display an [InputBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yfdhzk5(v=vs.84).aspx) from the VBS?

Comment: Please, explain more your aim. and edit your question to post some examples or codes to show us your real purpose !

Comment: Hello Tomalak, my *.bat has the logic to make the user's input (password) look like this: ***** It is fine, it works. The VBS inputbox has no such possibility (like e.g. the HTML input type "password"). So the *.bat's only reason to exist is to get the user's password data. It is important that noone in front of the PC could see the password clearly. (Sorry for my bad English.)

Comment: @Donny73Ger ==> Take a look at this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36012776/how-to-assign-password-to-secure-string-in-vb-script/36015770#36015770

Answer (score 1):

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
Sub ShowMenu
    Do
        ShowHelpMenu
        Answ=Inp.readline
        If Answ = "1" Then
            ShowGeneralHelp "TEXT"
        Elseif Answ = "2" Then
            ShowGeneralHelp "HTML"
        Elseif Answ = "3" Then
            Version
        Elseif Answ = "4" Then
            History
        Elseif Answ = "5" Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

To run

```
cscript //nologo 'c:\somefile.vbs"
```